# Как вывести в терминал только путь к нужной папке с помощью find?

Tags: ubuntu, консоль, find

Есть задача найти папку elasticsearch/bin где бы она не находилась в системе. По умолчанию путь к ней `"./[user_name]/share/elasticsearch/bin"`, но вместо пути по умолчанию может быть любой путь. Решил эту задачу следующей командой в терминале:

```
sudo find / -type d -wholename "*/elasticsearch/bin"'
```

Но на вывод в терминал кроме нужного пути пришло это:

```
/home/user/elasticsearch/bin
find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
find: ‘/run/user/1000/doc’: Permission denied
```

Как убрать из вывода Permission denied строки? Нужно оставить только путь в качестве вывода.

Comment: "Permission denied", скорее всего, идут в stderr, так что не парьтесь о них. Другое дело, что у вас может найтись более одного каталога elasticsearch/bin, так что метод такой себе.

Comment: просто добавьте папку `/run` в исключения `-not -path ...`